# Review step not loading in checkout?

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9.3.9

I just cant get to the review step in my standard **1.9.3.9** checkout. I checked the response of savePayment and it looks ok, the code for the review is there and looks ok, but its not "put" in the next section.

This is the beginning of the response: `{"goto_section":"review","update_section":{"name":"review"...`

This is my review section:

```
<li id="opc-review" class="section">
    <div class="step-title">
        <span class="number">6</span>
        <h2>Bestellübersicht</h2>
        <a href="#">Bearbeiten</a>
    </div>
    <div id="checkout-step-review" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
    </div>
</li>
```